# PySimpleGui: window sometimes not showing on mac

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

I created a GUI by using PySimpleGui and have a window that opens other windows. However, sometimes these new windows are not visible. I see that there are there in the dock but can't see them on the screen.

The spooky thing is that it happens randomly. Sometimes everything works fine and suddenly a single window won't open.

I have had a similar issue with pygame one where the main window also sometimes wasn't visible but showing in the dock.

(I'm using a m1 Mac running Mac os Big Sur and running python 3.10 (however when I had the issue with pygame I was on 3.9)

**This is an example**

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def create_window():
    layout = [
        [
            sg.Button("Create Window", key="-NEWWINDOW-"),
        ],
    ]

    return sg.Window(
        "Test",
        layout,
        font="normal 18",
    )


window = create_window()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == "-NEWWINDOW-":
        ans = sg.popup_ok_cancel(
            f"This is a popup but it behaves the same as a window",
            title='New "Window"',
            keep_on_top=True,
            font="normal 18",
        )

window.close()
```

Once I execute it, the first window opens (most at the time) and when I click on the "create window" button, the popup doesn't show up (most at the time). If it shows up I can close the popup and after clicking on the "create window" button again it always works until I exit the whole program.

[Here is a picture of what it looks like when the popup doesn't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCyhn.png)

Here are the failure rates where "p" means that the popup didn't show up, "w" means that the window didn't show up and "-" means that everything worked:

w w - - p - p p p p p p p p - - - - - - - p - - p - - - - - p -

Comment: saying that something is "spooky" is not useful. The community can help if you ask questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, I edited it. I hope someone can help me

Comment: Maybe same issue as https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/5471

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have already seen it but no solution was found.

Comment: It seems related to the tkinter version number.  8.6.12 has been a struggle.

Comment: how do I find out my Tkinter version?

Comment: If you want to do it through PySimpleGUI, `import PySimpleGUI as sg;sg.popup(sg.framework_version);sg.popup_scrolled(sg.get_versions())` will give you both the tkinter detailed version and the PySimpleGUI version info.

Comment: Thanks, here are my versions: Python version: 3.10.4
Port: PySimpleGUI
tkinter version: 8.6.12
PySimpleGUI version: 4.58.0 – so my only option is to wait for an update?